# Not able to install PyQt4 on a macOS Catalina

Tags: python, macos, homebrew

I am not able to install PyQt4 on a macOS Catalina. I have tried the following:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pyqt4
```

but I get a `apt-get command not found`. I installed homebrew and got fatal error. Some other command I tried:

```
pip install pyqt
brew install sip --with-python3
brew install pyqt --with-python3
brew install qt
brew install sip
brew install pyqt
```

But nothing works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`apt-get` is a package manager for certain Linux distros.

PyQT4 is no longer supported, try installing PyQT5 with this command: `pip install PyQt5`.

Comment: Thank you Kareem, that worked. It's installed.

Answer (score 0):

If you REALLY need version 4, it is still possible to install it, although it isn't actively maintained, so a move to version 5 may be in order.
PyQt4 supports Python v2 and v3 and is install-able if you use the specific version of both SIPv4 and PyQt4 from Riverbank:

[SIPv4 From Riverbank](https://riverbankcomputing.com/software/sip/download)

[PyQt4 From Riverbank](https://riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download)